# Google TMS links legal for usage in OL, GeoNode, QGIS?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, license, pricing

I really like to use the Google tms urls in OpenLayers, QGIS (QuickMapServices), GeoNode, like https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}

But is it legal to use this links? 
Will my server IP get blocked after a limit of demands?
Can i buy it somewhere or is it open for usage, unlimited usage?

I don't think that the Google Map Api is really fitting this case, because I dont use the API(no js, no styling) just the tms(xyz urls): https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/?hl=en

Have anybody experiences about that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the [help](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) explicitly says that "We are not a formal GIS Software Support Site and are likely to close questions and recommend you seek official routes for support if you ... ask about licensing, pricing and/or release dates"

Comment: The question is all about if anybody have any experiences about that because as self declared exchange (in GIS questions) forum it must be possible to ask others if they had experiences in this cases, because its not about the software itself, more about the TMS services and what could be more GISier than geospatial data.

Comment: Stack Exchange provides sites for focused Q&A - [they are not forums](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums).  If you prefer to call them that then I hope you will learn that they operate very differently to any discussion forums or other Q&A sites that you may have used.  The [Tour] (which you appear not to have taken) is designed to introduce all GIS SE users to its protocols.  You can always ask about experiences of others in the [GIS Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis).